# making a Curtom class from a custom function

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development and i am trying to make a custom class which I can access in my activities to read text from files on a server. i have a custom function which works fine but i need to access this function in many activities so i need a custom class which performs the same action. My function is here

```
public String GetLinkss(String url)  {
    String StringBuffer="";
    String stringText="";
        try {
            URL link = new URL(url);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));

            while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringText += StringBuffer;
            }
            bufferReader.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return stringText;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a package like this:

```
package com.whatever.utils;
public class Utils {
    private Context mContext;
    // constructor
    public Utils(Context activityContext) {
        mContext = activityContext;
    }

    public static String GetLinkss(String url) {
        // your stuff
    }
    // other functions/methods used throughout the application
}
```

And then you use it like this wherever you want:

```
String myStringText = Utils.GetLinkss("my_url");
```

HTH

Comment: will all the functions that i put in this class will be accessable throught the application?

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. Half of my headache is gone.. Sorry don't have enough reputation to up the answer :)